# How spark selects cassandra node for read?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have Cassandra cluster with N nodes on N machines. Also I have spark worker on every machine. For reading from Cassandra I'm using Datastax spark-cassandra connector. When I'm setting workers (Standalone mode) I only say master host for them. In driver I'm specifying Cassandra seeds by spark.cassandra.connection.host property. I saw many presentations about data locality.But I found no info about how spark-cassandra connector selects local node for each worker. Which algorithm connector uses for this?

Answer (score 0):

The connector is token-aware. It ensures data locality by adding token range filtering such as `token("partition-key") > ? AND token("partition-key") <= ?` to the query you run.

The connector uses  the parameter **spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb** (default to 64MB) to generate queries (`token(...) >? AND token(...)< ?`) that will load about 64MB of data in each Spark partition.

Comment: But how spark worker understand that exactly it should read some data? How it recognizes local cassandra node?

Comment: The driver is establishing an initial connection to the Cassandra cluster. It discovers the Cassandra topology and token distributions. I am assuming that it next matches the worker IPs to the Cassandra IPs  to know what query to generate to what workers for data locality.