# How Spark-cassandra-connector determines the range to query on Cassandra?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a three node Cassandra cluster with Spark executor running on each node. I understand that to scan the Cassandra database, `SCC`(Spark-Cassandra-Connector) uses range query putting tokens in where clause. How a SCC instance running on different node is able to select ranges different from other SCC instances running on other nodes. For example a SCC instance `A` on node1 picks a range `RangeA`, then how SCC instances `B` and `C` decides not to use the same range `RangeA`?

Do they communicate with each other?

Comment: I've tried to answer to your question with more pointers to the source code

Answer (score 3):

Driver when executing the action is generating the list of partitions that will be then mapped into Spark partitions and distributed between the worker nodes.  The generation of partitions really depends on the multiple factors (you can look into [ScanHelper.getPartitionGenerator function](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/datasource/ScanHelper.scala#L160)):

- does the WHERE condition contain the partition key or not
- is partition count already specified or not

Based on that, it's returning an instance of the [CassandraPartitionGenerator class](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/rdd/partitioner/CassandraPartitionGenerator.scala) that is performing real generation of partitions with [`partitions` function](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/rdd/partitioner/CassandraPartitionGenerator.scala#L80) that fetch the list of token ranges from the cluster , if necessary splits these token ranges into the smaller token ranges, group them by to which nodes they belong, etc.

That instance of `CassandraPartitionGenerator` is then used either by DataFrame or RDD APIs to get the list of Spark partitions that will be scheduled for execution by Spark.  And at the end these partitions are converted into the CQL `where` clauses by [CqlTokenRange class](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/rdd/partitioner/CassandraPartition.scala#L10).

P.S. Russel Spitzer also wrote a [blog post](http://www.russellspitzer.com/2017/09/01/Spark-Locality/) on Spark data locality & the Spark Cassandra Connector - this could be also useful for understanding.

Answer (score 2):

## Spark-cassandra-connector basics

The `spark-cassandra-connector` has fairly complicated internals, but the most important things (overly simplified) are the following:

- the connector would naturally prefer to `query locally`. E.g to avoid network and to have the `spark executor` **query its local** `cassandra` node
- to do that, the driver needs to understand the Cassandra topology and where the token ranges you need to query are (there is an initial `ring describe` done by the driver, so after that there is a full understanding where to find what part of your token)
- after understanding where the token ranges are, and mapping each token to an IP, the connector spreads the work in such a way that each local spark executor queries that part of the range that is local to it

## More detailed information

It's a bit more complex than that, but that's it in a nutshell. I think this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ikCzILOpYvA) from Datastax explains it a bit better.

You might also want to consider [reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36871814/how-spark-selects-cassandra-node-for-read) this question (with, admittedly, a vague answer).

## How you structure your data is important for this to work out of the box

Note that there is a bit of skill/knowledge required to structure your data and your query in such a way that the driver can try to do that.

Actually, the **most common type of performance problems** usually stem from badly structured data or queries leading to **non-local execution**. The `datastax java` driver, and the `spark-cassandra-connector` internally **try their best effort** to make the queries local, but you need to **also follow the best practices** in structuring your data. If you haven't already done so, I recommend reading/going through the trainings described in the [Data Modeling By Example](https://www.datastax.com/learn/data-modeling-by-example) articles by DataStax.

## Edit: queries without locality

As you mentioned, sometimes the executors don't reside on the same host as the nodes. Still, the principle is the same:

When you have a query, it is over a certain token range. Some of the data for this query will be "owned" by `node A`, some of the data will be "owned" by `node B`, and some by `node C`.

The `ring describe` operation tells the driver, for a certain range, which part of it is in `node A`, which in `node B`, and which in `node C`. The driver then essentially **splits the query in 3 subqueries** and asks for it from the appropriate nodes which own the particular range.

Each node responds with their own portion, and at the end the driver aggregates it.

You might notice that **local or not**, the principle is exactly the same:

> *ask each node only about the particular range it owns, which the driver learned earlier by using the `ring describe` operation*.

Hope that makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: What if not able to get locality (spark executor on same host machine as Cassandra node)? For example in K8S environment, I am not able to get executor and Cassandra node to run on same pod/container. How will different SCC instances identify their ranges?

Comment: If not able to do local execution, then simply each instance of the spark executor will get a "piece" of the token range and execute it against the selected node. The principle here (apart from locality) is the same: each executor gets its own piece of the range and connects that to the cassandra node where this piece is located (which is known by initially describing the token range).

Comment: I am not sure if I understood it well enough. As per my understanding you are saying SCC is Cassandra topology aware and will pick or try to pick those ranges which are local to it. But if localization cannot be achieved, then how SCC will pick its token range.

Comment: It really doesn't matter if local or not (although local is preferred, if possible). The fact that it is topology aware is all that's relevant here, it means for any given query (for a cluster of 3 nodes), it can be split into 3 subqueries: 1 for each of the nodes. Each of those subqueries is then  "delegated" to a different executor which in turn hits the Cassandra node where the data for this subquery is located.

Comment: it's not necessary the 3 queries :-)