# Does Spark Allow Running On Multiple Nodes?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using Cassandra and I have 3 nodes (rf:3) each of that have 20 core, each of that has 1tb SSD, and each of that has 64GB ram. But when I connect Cassandra from spark and try to read data only which I use node CPU's working,  all of the cores that computer working 90% 80% level but the other computers (nodes) CPU's does not change they are not working. Does Spark Allow Running On Multiple Nodes? if yes, How can provide that?

I am giving 3 node ip's to the connection host like below but it does not work.

```
hosts ={"spark.cassandra.connection.host":'node1_ip,node2_ip,node3_ip',
   "table":"ex_table","keyspace":"ex_keyspace"}
data_frame=sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
  .options(**hosts).load()
```

Comment: what kind of data processing are you performing after you load the data?

Comment: How do you run Spark, is it launched on a separate server(s)?

Comment: @HadesArchitect                                         
**Step summary:**
1.  Run in your master machine :
 ./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
   It will give us IP:PORT
2. Run in your workers machine:
   ./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://IP:PORT
3. To create and deploy Spark code application, type : "pyspark --master spark://IP:PORT" in your master cluster.                                                                       
i tried to use but it didn't run for worker for step two and i got it ""failed to connect master spark""

Comment: @AlexOtt Just read data from cassandra and i tried to save as csv file.

Comment: The spark-cassandra-connector internally try their best effort to make the queries local.
So if the all the data that you are trying to read are present in the same node, it will read it from that node. You need to restructure your data between the nodes to make spark use all the nodes.
It is better explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68430885/how-spark-cassandra-connector-determines-the-range-to-query-on-cassandra